# WidgetView on Xcode 14

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, widget

The moment I set a SwiftUI View's preview context to WidgetPreviewContext, Xcode shows an error saying

"UnableToFindPreviewHostError: Could not find host for previews

Could not find a host (app, extension, framework) given the open files and active `PreviewProvider` types. Make sure the open files and `PreviewProvider` types are target in the active scheme.

sources: , SubManagerWidgetView.swift
commonAncestors: SubManager.app
graph:
target app SubManager.app (#1)
translationUnit SubManagerWidgetView.swift (#2)
Preview   (#3)"

Does anybody know the reason for this?

By the way, my code is:

```
import SwiftUI
import WidgetKit

struct SubManagerWidgetView: View {
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
   }
}

struct SubManagerWidgetView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    Group {
        SubManagerWidgetView()
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
      }
   }
}
```